# Looking up multiple values in a list

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I'm trying to select multiple values based on a search key. In it's most basic form there is no problem with this. I followed this example and everything went well:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/how-to-look-up-a-value-in-a-list-and-return-multiple-corresponding-values-HA001226038.aspx

```
=IF(ISERROR(INDEX($A$1:$B$7,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$7=$A$10,ROW($A$1:$A$7)),ROW(1:1)),2)),"",INDEX($A$1:$B$7,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$7=$A$10,ROW($A$1:$A$7)),ROW(1:1)),2))
```

The problem with this however is that in my case I have multiple CSV files (external) where some values in my `A$` column look like this:

```
=- sometext // results into #NAME? error
```

Excel interprets these as a formulas where it is actually only supposed to be a string. Sure I could change it to text and save it again but I would like to avoid any manipulation in these CSV files.

I tried to extend the second `IF` statement (if you read it from left to right) with:

```
IF(AND($A$1:$A$7 <> "#NAME?", $A$1:$A$7=$A$10,ROW($A$1:$A$7)))
```

and

```
IF(AND(NOT(ISERROR($A$1:$A$7)), $A$1:$A$7=$A$10,ROW($A$1:$A$7)))
```

Both didn't work. (Sorry if I messed up some syntax and formula names, I'm using a different language version)

Here a small image of what's happening right now and how it should look:

[image]

On the right site you can see a list of values right next to `Test1` which are missing on the left site due to the `#NAME?` error.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest opening the csv's files as text files. Selecting `Comma` as your delimiter and then select `Text` as your Column data format. This way, Excel will treat all your data as text and will not try to read `=- sometext` as a formula.

To do so, you would need to change your `.csv` files extension to .txt or anything else (even no file format).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "Opening" the CSV file, you can "Import" it.  This will open the Text Import Wizard which will allow you to specify particular columns as Text.  This is located in different areas in different versions of Excel.  In Excel 2007, it is on the Data Tab / Get External Data / From Text.  The example below demonstrates bringing in long numbers, but it should work just as well with your formula "lookalikes"

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not opening the csv files at all. I'm only refering to them as external source. `'C:\Reports\[Budget.csv]Annual'!C10:C25` The image above is only to illustrate the output but the list with `TestX`is in an external file. The csv files contian the list and the excel file (different file) is using it as database. And I'would like to avoide any operations like loading/importing the file since these would be additional clicks or actions for someone to perform.

Comment: IF you don't want to import the csv file into Excel, you could probably import the Data into Access, or maybe SQL Express, and then use the Data Connection feature in Excel.  Or you could write a VBA routine to access the data and ensure it is formatted correctly.

Comment: Also, when you Import the first time, you will set up a connection that you can later refresh.  Perhaps you could have the data on a separate, hidden sheet.